# Can I use a UserControl to reuse a DropDownExtender despite having page-specific parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

In my application, I have a large number of pages that repeat very similar grids, and every single one is going to have a 'DropDownExtender' ajax control in the leftmost column, which will contain many links to other pages for that row.

Now, I'd like to avoid code repetition by having this DropDownExtender as a user control. However, one crucial aspect of this is that the control will contain some hidden fields/values for the links that are relating to that specific row - for example, I have

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ID")' />
```

I'm assuming this would not work - how would I pass over the values to the user control in an efficient manner?

Comment: "I'd like to avoid code reuse". You mean the opposite, no? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a public property in your user control it can be set either in code or in the markup, just as you are doing with the hidden field above.

You may also need:

```
[Bindable(BindableSupport.Yes)]
```

If you need data-binding support.

Answer (score 0):

If i right understend you - you need to have a unique identifier for each control, right? If i right you can do next:

UserControl1.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebUserControl1.ascx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebUserControl1" %>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnID" runat="server" Value='<%# Bind("ID")' />
```

and UserControl1.cs:

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebUserControl1 : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        public string HiddenFildProperty
        {
            get { return hdnID.Value; }
            set { hdnID.Value = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

and than you can use this control in any template controls, such as Repeater, like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <mycontrols:WebUserControl1 ID="myControl1" HiddenFildProperty='<%#Bind("ID") %>'/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The same way, you can bind any other properties in your control, for exaple directly link in your DropDownExtander.